# Have cron only send mail when PHP throws an error

Tags: php, email, cron, stderr

I've a few cronjobs that run small PHP scripts every 1 or 2 minutes. Obviously I don't want e-mail every minute. I do want to know when the cron failed or when it encountered any kind of error (= notice, warning, error or uncaught exception).

My PHP scripts print a lot of meta data (using `echo`) so it can be run manually and inspected. I want all of that meta data to be sent to me IF an error occurred. If no error occurred, I don't want mail, but because there's output, cron sends me an e-mail anyway.

Is there a way to have cron ONLY send me the entire output IF an error occurred?

- I don't want to manually send an e-mail
- I rather not use ob (if that's even possible inside a cronjob)
- I'm Okay with changing my output method (`print` or a custom function instead of `echo` etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out crronic - it's a shell wrapper that provides this functionality:

http://habilis.net/cronic/

Note that you'll need to exit with a nonzero exit value in case of an error (in order to trigger the mail).

Comment: Oeh I like that. How do I add it so that I can run it everywhere? I don't want to `/root/tools/cronic /usr/bin/php /var/www/br2pr/source/cronjobs/script.php`. That's too long.

Comment: That's what you're stuck with unfortunately.  Don't worry about it being too long, cron doesn't care.  :)

Comment: But I do, because it's in my mail message. I can add `cronic` to my `$PATH` or something right? Like `php`?